# FileNotFoundException Pointing at \bin\debug\application.exe During DataSet.ReadXML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, impersonation, delegation

I am writing a C# solution called "BatchReader".   In this app, I have an XMLDocument object instantiated from a FileInfo object.   The FileInfo object is created by obtaining a set of folder paths from my app.config file, and stored in a String array called uncPaths.   These folder paths resemble:

> \\devServer\Applications\BatchReader\Inbound\error

```
Boolean retVal = LogonUser("user", "domain", "pw",LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);
if (!retVal)
{
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
throw new Win32Exception(error);
}
using (safeTokenHandle)
{
   using (WindowsIdentity newID = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
   {
      using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newID.Impersonate())
      {
         foreach (String networkPath in uncPaths)
         {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(networkPath);
            if(!dir.Exists)
            {
               continue;
            }

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(fileMaskString);

            foreach(FileInfo file in files)
            {
               using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
               {
                  xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                  xmlDoc.Load(fs);
               }

               XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
               XPathNavigator searchNode = nav.SelectSingleNode(xPathQuery);

               if(searchNode!=null)
               {
                  DataSet xmlAsDataSet = new DataSet();
                  XmlNodeReader xnr = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
                  xmlAsDataSet.ReadXml(xnr);
               }
            }
         }
```

The user selects from a set of dropdowns to determine what the xPath string and filename mask.   Stepping through the code, I know that I'm able to retrieve data from this FileInfo object successfully.   I then convert this XML doc to a DataSet for later processing.

When I run this code on my machine, the code executes properly.   However, when I have a tester step through the code on their machine, I get a FileNotFoundException when the below line of code executes:

```
xmlAsDataSet.ReadXml(xnr);
```

Strangely, the error message for this exception points at the debug executable (.exe) file for my application.   (Example: C:\BatchReader\bin\Debug\BatchReader.exe).

Can someone please explain why DataSet.ReadXML is somehow considering where the BatchReader.exe file is located?

Comment: is the tester actually stepping thru the code using Visual Studio.. or are they just launching the application... sounds like a path issue ..meaning the user does not have the same path setup on their machine.. I would recommend or suggest that if you are reading a file or files, that you use the app.Config file and define the file path in the config file along with the name.. if there are going to be multiple files to be processed then only define the file path ..Do not HardCode values...this is your first mistake if you are doing it that way..

Comment: `using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead()` what is the file path in regards to file.OpenRead.. please show where you define the filepath and name.. I would guess that in your Bin Directory .. you already have a copy of the file you are expecting to process.. which again is not a good place either this is what I would guess to be the issue

Comment: They are stepping through the code and running locally.   The final file path is based off of the directory path (loaded from app.config as you say) and a call to DirectoryInfo.GetFiles, passing in a filename mask.   The bin directory is NOT contained in my config file.   That folder is totally unrelated to the directories located in my config file.

Comment: well it's probably looking there because it can't create on in the proper place and normally it will place it in the directory of where the application was launched if the filename and path have not been properly specified.. also I've never seen or worked in an environment where users can actually step thru the code.. LOL what type of place are you working in... what happens if someone changes your code..?

Comment: The tester in this instance is another developer, and I'm watching him step through the code, so I know he's not making any modifications.   The reason I'm having him test is that his machine resembles that of an end-user, whereas my machine has additional file access privileges.   The application is using the authentication method LogonUser stored in the advapi32.dll file.   However, I wish to emphasize that the user **can** access the file in question.   In the above example, the SelectSingleNode method returns successfully.   The error occurs AFTER this method is called.

Comment: ok so I ask this after this line `XPathNavigator searchNode = nav.SelectSingleNode(xPathQuery);` where does it actually error? please provide more information.. also if you have additional access privileges ... then does the other developer testing this have enough or the same to successfully run the processes end to end..  ? if not then common sense would tell you that it's a `Rights Issue` don't you think

Comment: It could be a permissions error, but as I posted in the updated code, I am impersonating a user (username: "user" in the above example) that **does** have read access to the network drive and the files I'm searching through.   I've confirmed that by manually logging into this account and checking the files.

Comment: Impersonation is a good way to test but could have some negative impacts I think it's better to fix the issue than to bandage it so to speak.. anyway let us know if that fixes your issues temporarily

Comment: The impersonation is happening standardly as a part of the application code.   It's supposed to be how users access the data inside of the files.

Comment: I think that's a poor mans work around when infact this can be done if the system admin just sets up user rights .. and I know that this can also be done at a group level too.. I personally am against implementing `Impersonation`

Comment: I agree that system admins can grant access to the folders.   In fact, that's one thing that I've already tried - I gave the tester read access to the directories being searched, yet the same error (pointing at my debug folder) still appears.

Comment: that sounds to me like there is not a valid path defined and even if it creates a file with no defined path...it will create a file in the file location of the executed / running application ..which in your case as well as many will be created in the `Bin` Directory..